# libmpfr.so.4 dependency with --disable-shared

Tags: linux, gcc, toolchain, mpfr

everyone!
I have the same result 
**

> error while loading shared libraries: libmpfr.so.4: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory

but under another configure :

```
../gcc.s/configure      \
--target=$LFS_TGT       \
--prefix=/tools     \
--with-sysroot=$LFS     \
--with-newlib       \
--without-headers       \
--with-local-prefix=/tools  \
--with-native-system-header-dir=/tools/include  \
--disable-nls       \
--disable-shared        \
--disable-multlib       \
--disable-decimal-float \
--disable-threads       \
--disable-libmudflap    \
--disable-libssp        \
--disable-libgomp       \
--disable-libquadmath   \
--enable-language=c
```

having gmp, mpc, mpfr present in the GCC source tree

My question is 
how did it turn out that `--disable-shared`
enable to link cc1 against `libmpfr.so.4` insteed static `libmpfr.a`
which is present in gcc build results:

```
gcc.b/mpfr/src/.libs/libmpfr.a
```

Comment: Read the gcc doc, --disable-shared doesn't do what you think it does. Now when mpfr is built in-tree, normally only libmpfr.a is built. Why it finds the system libmpfr.so before that one needs investigating, you should log all the output during the compilation and then search for the linker call that linked with mpfr.

Answer (score 0):

First, run `pacman -Syu` and perform any/all updates. ***Make sure to pay attention to pacman's output*** (inspect `/var/log/pacman.log` if there is a alot of output). Look for and merge any .pacnew's found, the log will show the location of these files or you could also `ls -al /etc/*.pacnew`, but check the logs anyways to make sure you didn't miss any in any sub directories or other locations . Also, if a kernel is updated make sure to reboot. If that doesn't solve the issue then rebuild mpfr against the newest libraries.

[Here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacnew_and_Pacsave_Files) is a link to the Arch Linux Wiki on handling .pacnew and .pacsave files.

#### Perform full update

`# pacman -Syu`

#### If mpfr doesn't fix from just an update

`# pacman -Syu mpfr` ***Always*** use `-Syu` when installing / updating to make sure all repo's are up to updated.

#### Checking libmpfr.so.* ownership.

`# pacman -Qo /usr/lib/libmpfr.so`

`/usr/lib/libmpfr.so.4.1.1 is owned by mpfr 3.1.1.p2-2`

If you run into any issues after updating please paste logs and error msgs on a pastebin site and I'll have a look.

**Sorry**,
I thought that this was tagged `[archlinux]` but it obviously is not *(Thank you Jonathan Wakely)*. The same steps apply though. Replace `pacman -*` with your distributions package manager `apt-get`, `yum`, `emerge`, whatever it may be. mpfr has to be rebuilt against the newer library.

Comment: This is specific to Arch Linux ... is the OP using Arch?

Comment: I'm not going to lie. I could have sworn it was tagged archlinux.